# Loop advantages/disadvantages

Tags: c#, loops

I am curious about other languages, but for the sake of specification I will ask about C#. Lets say I have a program with multiple simple loops:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());

 for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++)
     MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());

 for (int i = 20; i < 30; i++)
     MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
```

If I choose to make i a global variable:

```
 int i;

 for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());

 for ( i = 10; i < 20; i++)
     MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());

 for ( i = 20; i < 30; i++)
     MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
```

Is one way faster than another? Does one way consume more memory than another?

Comment: Is the point of the question the local vs global variable, or the loop? The answer of course is no difference either way.

Comment: As @Jon said, there is no difference, you just need to check if you need the variable after the loop. You can init the `i` variable in every `for` statement.

Comment: Eric Lippert: "If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses. Don’t write short descriptions of the horses, post them on the Internet, and ask random strangers to guess which is faster!" Please read: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Also you can use LDasm tool to compare generated IL-code. There can be some interesting things (not in that case though).

Comment: In the first scenario, there's a high chance the compiler will reuse the same memory slot for all 3 declarations of `i`.

Comment: @tnw How would you go about benchmarking the computational time of something so small, and how can I benchmark what is happening with memory?

Comment: @TheBlindSpring Doesn't matter how small it is, you can still benchmark it. Look it up, you can most definitely do both of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be any noticeable difference between performances.
The second program will be a `little` faster than the first but remember the word only a little.

Let me tell you why in the 1st program variable i will have to be created 3 different times as every time i will only have a block scope so let's assume the time for creating a variable i in memory is a and time for destroying it from memory is b.

Now in the first program the time taken will be time to execute instructions + 3a +3b as variable i is loaded 3 times and destroyed 3 times.

Now in the second program the time taken will be time to execute instructions + a +b as variable i is loaded into memory once and destroyed after the program finishes.

a and b are very small values unless you are using a machine with `very very` slow processing speed therefore there won't be any noticeable difference in performances.

Answer (score 0):

when you declare a variable, your computer reserve a memory space for that variable. when no method invokes its, computer check it as "unused" and release the memory space. obviously these operations take cpu time, but is so little time and your cpu is so fast that you'll even notice the differences (unless you have a 10Hz processor :P )
So, on theoric line, the second program is faster than the first one.